# Backtransform word tokens to a sentence-based corpus in Quanteda after preprocessing

Tags: r, quanteda, data-preprocessing

I want to preprocess my text data using the `{quanteda}` package in R. To do so, I am creating a corpus, which is then tokenized and preprocessed (e.g. lowercase, remove punctuation, etc.).

Ideally, I would then want to restore the initial sentence structure of the corpus, **whilst keeping the document variables**, because I am following a string-of-words approach in the analysis.

```
# Create an example corpus.
my_corpus <- corpus(c("This is a sentence. \n\nThis is another sentence.", 
                      "This is the first sentence of the second document.",
                      "This is yet another ... ••• *** sentence."))

# Set docvars.
docvars(my_corpus) <- data.frame(doc_id = 1:3, author = c("A", "B", "C"))

# Three documents and four sentences.
ndoc(my_corpus)
nsentence(my_corpus)

# Tokenize and preprocess.
my_tokens <- my_corpus %>%
  tokens(remove_punct = T) %>%
  tokens_tolower()

my_tokens

# Docvars are still present.
docvars(my_tokens)
```

I could then simply do the following to restore the sentence structure. However, in the process of doing so, I would lose my docvars:

```
# Back-transform to sentences.
my_corpus.clean <- vapply(my_tokens, paste, collapse = " ", character(1)) %>% corpus()

# Docvars are lost.
docvars(my_corpus.clean)
```

The preprocessing worked and so did restoring the sentence structure, but I no longer have my docvars. I could then add them back to the new corpus object (`docvars(...) <- ...`), but am afraid that the docvars values will no longer correspond to the right documents.

Is there a way to transform the tokens object back to a sentence-based object that avoids losing the docvars?

Comment: The solution to this is fairly simple but it would help ensure a robust answer if the example had included multi-sentence documents. But first I have to ask: Why do you need to split this into sentences before the removals in the tokenisation process?

Comment: Hi @KenBenoit ! Thanks, that's a good point. I actually don't need to do that prior to the tokenization and preprocessing. I edited my post trying to make this step clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this at the end:

```r
# back-transform to sentences.
my_corpus.clean <- vapply(my_tokens, paste, collapse = " ", character(1)) |>
    corpus(docvars = docvars(my_tokens))

# docvars are present
my_corpus.clean
#> Corpus consisting of 3 documents and 2 docvars.
#> text1 :
#> "this is a sentence this is another sentence"
#> 
#> text2 :
#> "this is the first sentence of the second document"
#> 
#> text3 :
#> "this is yet another sentence"

docvars(my_corpus.clean)
#>   doc_id author
#> 1      1      A
#> 2      2      B
#> 3      3      C
```

Comment: Oh wow, that's actually really straightforward. Just one question: wouldn't it be faster and neater to allow something like this `tokens(my_corpus, what = "sentence", remove_symbols = T, remove_punct = T)` instead of having to turn everything into word tokens and then restore the sentence structure?

Comment: Just wondering bc. I could obviously just do `str_remove_all(my_corpus, c("\\bis\\b|\\ba\\b|\\bof\\b|\\bthe\\b|\\.|\\•|\\*")) %>% str_squish()`, which avoids the whole reshaping to words and then back to sentences, . . .right?

Comment: You can always manipulate the corpus directly, since it's just a character vector (with special attributes). But then you have to do it through regular expressions rather than through the tokens options, which are designed to be robust, consistent, and fast.